How to identify whether the partition belongs to OS (Linux) or not using python
I have a requirement to identify only the operating system volumes using python. Is there any method in "psutil" to identify that? Currently I'm thinking of to read fstab, based on the 6th column (if not "0") we have to identify whether the partition belongs to  OS or just data. Can some through some light on fstab reading is correct for my requirement or there is some easy way in python to identify this?

The sixth field is used to identify order of mounting and not a belonging. See fstab(5)

Can you give examples? What are "operating system volumes"? Also, that might clarify how Python is involved here, since there's no question about code here.

The partitions required to boot Linux (like on windows C drive)- I want to identify them programmatically and back up them.

You can [edit] that into your question. Anyhow, how would you do that? That would answer how to do it with Python.

forget about python - given a Linux machine how to identify the operating system related partitions?
